# jQuery animation: move image up-down in smaller height div with overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danradic/VqzvR/2/)! 
 
The image should move up until it's bottom edge reaches the bottom of div and then move down until it's top edge reaches the top edge of parent div, to reveal it.
This has to work with different sized images.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  move();
});

function move() {
  $(".image").animate({
    bottom: "-=50%"
  }, 10000, 'linear', function() {
    $(".image").animate({
      bottom: "+=50%"
    }, 10000, 'linear', move);
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 1100px;
  height: 480px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="http://www.hotel-aramis.com/slider/home/notre-dame-de-paris.jpg />
    </div>
```

Comment: So what is not working! I mean what problem you are facing?

Comment: The problem is that I want it to show only the image, from top to bottom. As you can see in the fiddle, the background of the parent div is showing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  move();
});

function move() {
  $img = $(".image");
  var i = new Image();
  i.src = $img.attr('src');

  var d = i.height - $('.container').height();

  $img.animate({
    bottom: "+="+d+'px'
  }, 10000, 'linear', function () {
    $img.animate({
        bottom: "-="+d+'px'
    }, 10000, 'linear', move);
  });
}
```

This is a little sneaky, it creates a new javascript image Object (non Jquery) using the same src as the selected one and uses its natural height to perform the animation. It seems that if we create a jQuery object its height isn't the same, maybe it needs to be attached to the dom or similar.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VqzvR/8/

moving the setup code outside of the `move()` function will mean that the http get (for the img src) will only be performed once:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setupMove();
});

function setupMove() {
  $img = $(".image");
  var i = new Image();
  i.src = $img.attr('src');

  var d = i.height - $('.container').height();

  function move() {
    $img.animate({
        bottom: "+="+d+'px'
    }, 10000, 'linear', function () {
        $img.animate({
            bottom: "-="+d+'px'
        }, 10000, 'linear', move);
    });
  }
  move();
}
```

Is this the effect you were looking for?